# Symbol after \paragraph heading

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, paragraphs

I am using scrbook for my thesis (so no Titlesec) and would like to reformat the way paragraphs work in a very minor way: I need a symbol after the heading, with even spacing between the symbol and the following text. I am using this in a meaningful way (referring to sections within discussed works as I recap their contents), so resorting to other levels of sectioning is no good option.

Fooling around with various solutions for other related problems got me nowhere.

The result should look like:

> *Bacon is good*  |  dolores has an ipsum in her amet ....

[with a bit more space around the "|"]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just to make sure everyone is using the same terminology: By "paragraph", do you mean the LaTeX macro called `\paragraph`? Or are you referring to logical textual units called "paragraphs"? Please advise.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity - I meant the logical textual units, as in "one below \subsubsection".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that by the term "paragraph", you mean the LaTeX macro named `\paragraph`. Please advise if this is not what you have in mind.

Is the following close to what you had in mind?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\origpara}{\paragraph}
\renewcommand\paragraph[2][]{\origpara[#1]{#2}\quad\textbar\qquad}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Bacon is good}Lorem ipsum \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP will probably want something smaller than `\quad`, but that is easily changed. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot - this was the easy solution I assumed existed and couldn't fathom. 
For completeness - I used hspaces now and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine KOMA-Script command `\sectioncatchphraseformat` for `paragraph`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\normalfont\itshape}% change font settings for paragraph heading
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-.5em]{paragraph}% change horizontal skip after paragraph heading

\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{paragraph}
    {\hskip #2#3#4\hskip .5em{\normalfont\textbar}}% new definition for paragraph heading
    {\hskip #2#3#4}% orginal definition for other levels like subparagraph
}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Bacon is good}Lorem ipsum \dots
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Note that the `-` in `afterskip=-.5em` means that the skip is horizontal. So there is a skip of `.5em` to the right of the paragraph heading. The default value for `paragraph` is `afterskip=-1em`.

Comment: Thanks! Good to have two different ways of achieving a similar result, in case there should be conflict etc.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: there was a bit of an oddity with the spacing, so I had to fiddle. The result I was looking for was achieved with the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\origpara}{\paragraph}
\renewcommand\paragraph[2][]{\origpara[#1]{#2}\hspace{-0.5em}$\mid$\hspace{0.em}}

\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalfont\rmfamily\itshape}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Bacon is good} \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]